# Unable to clear Bash terminal history in OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osx-elcapitan

After upgrading to OS X El Capitan (at least I noticed after update), in bash, `history -c` command does not work as usual.

History clearing only works for current tab. After opening another tab, it is possible to access history.

I know it is possibly to remove `.bash_history` file but actually I am curious about this new behaviour?

Maybe it is related to new `.bash_sessions` feature. Is there any way to use `history -c` as usual (clearing history across every bash instances)?

Thanks.

Comment: [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) is a question and answer site for Apple enthusiasts and power users.

Comment: ...and question this isn't about programming, which is the **only** subject on-topic at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 16):

### HISTFILE Isn't ~/.bash_history

On OS X, the shell variable *HISTFILE* doesn't seem to point to ~/.bash_history. Instead, it points to some sort of temp file like:

> /Users/$LOGNAME/.bash_sessions/7F058D96-4161-4F7C-B9F7-CFFEB43C35B2.historynew

As a result, `history -c; history -w` clears the current history buffer, but doesn't actually clear the on-disk history file. It's unclear to me how/when the *HISTFILE* is written to ~/.bash_history, so you may need to clear the file manually. For example:

```
history -c; history -w; rm ~/.bash_history
```

Answer (score 3):

I used:

```
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -c
```

I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191999/how-to-clear-bash-history-completely) topic, maybe you could find more info there?

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** your bash History in the terminal is located in `~/.bash_history` or if you using oh-my-zsh in `~/.zsh_history`. Just open the file and delete the specific command line you wish for. I'm using vim but you can open it with any IDE or notepad and save the changes.